# Creating an accordion with jQuery, but got "$ is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, accordion

I'm trying to make a simple accordion (collapsible) to show different panels, when the button is clicked on, but for some reason, it's not working.

I looked at my DevTools and got **$ was used before it was defined**.

```js
$('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e) {
  $(this).next('.accordion-panel').not(':animated').slideToggle();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <button class="accordion-control">Phase one</button>
    <div class="accordion-panel">Context will go here</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

My script tag is right above my closing body tag and below my jQuery script. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you tried putting this all within $(document).ready(function() { //YOUR CODE HERE });

Comment: I thought that only mattered if I was using the function within the HTML code? Either way, I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call jQuery (*its shorthand* ***$***) before it's loaded and defined. Place your script in the right place (*in the bottom*) of the HTML's body tag, **then put your JavaScript code into** [**jQuery's ready function**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

---

## Your own version

```js
$(function() {
  $('.accordion').on('click', '.accordion-control', function(e) {
    $(this).next('.accordion-panel').not(':animated').slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>My Awesome Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="accordion">
    <li>
      <button class="accordion-control">Phase one</button>
      <div class="accordion-panel">Context will go here</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- Your script or source below. -->
  <script src="scripts/my-script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

## Using Bootstrap

**First**, use these templates below and put jQuery in the bottom of your HTML page, before the closing body tag, but before your actual script and Bootstrap's script:

## Bootstrap 3

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>My Awesome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Your script or source below. -->    
    <script src="scripts/my-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Accordions in Bootstrap 3**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

## Bootstrap 4

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>My Awesome Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello there!</h1>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Your script or source below. -->
    <script src="scripts/my-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[**Accordions in Bootstrap 4**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example)

---

**Then** put your JavaScript code into jQuery's [**ready**](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Your accordion code here
});
```

**OR** using it's shorthand version:

```
$(function () {
    // Your accordion code here
});
```

**OR** in [**ES6**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
$(() => {
    // Your accordion code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not about the accordion class, it is about the $ symbol that you are using.

You need to import jQuery in your code, for $ symbol to work.

Add `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` in your html head tag.

Here's the working version of your code available on Code Pen https://codepen.io/puneetpalkaur/pen/Wyyzrz?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a linter (JSLint/ESLint) warning. Use global directive in the source file to avoid the warning:

```
/*global $, jQuery*/
```